# Comparing Json from different sources

Tags: json, node.js

Here is a use case:

1PM* site is monitored

URL1: foo.com; the json response is {main:{id:1,name:John},{id:2,name:Lenny}}

URL2: bar.com; the json response is {main:{id:1,name:Michael}}

==========================

2PM site is monitored again

URL1: foo.com; the json response is {main:{id:1,name:Kevin},{id:2,name:Tim}

URL2: bar.com; the json response is {main:{id:1,name:Michael}}

=====================

I would want to compare URL1 and its json at 1 pm to URL1 and its json at 2 pm.

Questions
1) What is the best data structure(or database) to store URL1 and its Json along with url2 and its json?
2) Is there a way to log the differences from 1 PM to 2 PM?

*Note: these time frames are made up.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: I havent tried this is node yet, I am looking for the best/fastest practice to store. I did this in py and just used a string to compare.  I plan on using Node and expanding the size of the project as well so i want to make sure i do it the best way

Comment: Would storing 1 PMs json to a file name URL1.json be good than compare that file to the most up to date one or is this not the brightest idea

Comment: That's a fine way of doing it, unless you need to access it a lot or need any kind of speed. Personally I'd use MongoDB - but it is a lot more work to configure than just having a json file

Comment: It would be a faster interval than an hour, which would mean i need to access it quite a bit, and need it to be fast.  MongoDB would be the best solution in this case?

Comment: Yup, Mongo is the best approach, just much less simple for small projects. I've written you a short answer though

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 main options, either just have a `.json` file and read and write to it, or use [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/).

## Option #1 Reading/writing from a .json file

This is fast and easy to setup, but not a good option for larger data sets, or if frequent requests are required.

1. Create an object, and add some stuff into it

   `let obj = {myMessage: 'Hello'};`
2. Convert it from an object to string with stringify

   `var json = JSON.stringify(obj);`
3. Use fs to write the file to disk

   `const fs = require('fs');`

   `fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', callback);`
4. Then to read it back again

fs.readFile('myjsonfile.json',

```
 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
    obj = JSON.parse(data); //now it an object
    obj.table.push({id: 2, square:3}); //add some data
    json = JSON.stringify(obj); //convert it back to json
    fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', callback); // write it back 
}});
```

## Option #2 [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/)

This isn't hard to setup, but not as simple as the first approach. It is considerably more scalable, and will also alow for much faster access rates, as well as basic querying. It would defently be the prefered choice for most situations.

Check [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/) for getting started with Mongo.

Comment: I have the reading/writing down. I think i am going to go with mongo and learn something new.  Thanks.

Comment: ok so my use case is a bit different from the original formula. the ID will be unique all the time per name, 

so, I stored a URL1 1pm array of ids in mongo, then when i query the list of URL1 2pm arrays i will do a loop and compare each of the 2pm to the 1 pm, and if it is new then i will display it. This seems to get the job done, or should. Havent fully tested it but i believe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What is the best data structure(or database) to store URL1 and its Json along with url2 and its json?

That really depends on your exact use case as there are several different options. You could store them as plain JSON files or use a database that supports JSON (e.g. MongoDB, CouchDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL, [or something else](https://www.quackit.com/json/tutorial/list_of_json_databases.cfm)).

> 2) Is there a way to log the differences from 1 PM to 2 PM?

The best way to do that is probably [JSON Patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Patch) (but again, that depends on your exact use case). JSON Patch is a web standard by the IETF. It defines a patch format that can be retrieved from the difference of two JSON data structures or can be applied to a JSON structure (hence, the name "JSON Patch"). There are [implementations of JSON Patch in different programming languages](http://jsonpatch.com/#libraries).